# HTTPS (SSL) works on firefox but not smartphone app

Tags: javascript, php, android, angularjs, https

I'm developing an application with phonegap and Ionic and having difficulties with HTTPS (SSL). I'm puzzled over why this refuses to work.
It works like a charm on Firefox but when I'm running it on my phone it doesn't work.

If I use normal HTTP it works fine but HTTPS doesn't, I assume it got something to do with the port 443 used for SSL but no idea how to check it on my smartphone (android).

**Question:**
Why does HTTPS not work on my smartphone and how do I get it to work?

**Login code:**

```
$scope.login = function(name, password) {
    $scope.type = 'login';

    // Data to be sent to the database
    var data = JSON.stringify({
                        type: $scope.type,
                        name: name.toLowerCase(),
                        password: password
                    });

    var useSSL = false; 
    // Call httpPost from app.js with this scope and the data to be inserted
    $scope.httpPost($scope, data, $scope.type, useSSL);
};
```

**Function: httpPost**

```
$rootScope.httpPost = function(scope, question, type, SSL) {
    var urlBase = "http";
    if (SSL) urlBase = "https";

    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: urlBase+"://mydomain.xyz/myproject/api.php",
        crossDomain : true,
        data: question,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
    /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
    request.success(function(data) {
        if (type == "login"){
            // Confirm it's a valid token
            if(data.length == 10){ 
                showAlert('confirmation', 'you are now online');
            }
            else{
                showAlert('Try again', 'wrong credentials');
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // No response from server
        // This is what triggers and the data returned is useless
        showAlert('Ooops', JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

**Serverside**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        // Retrieve the incoming data
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

        // Check if the data is defined
        if (isset($postdata)) {

            // Parse the incoming data
            $request = json_decode($postdata);

            // Connect to database
            include 'connect.php';
            $db = Database::getInstance();
            $db->connect();


            // Login attempt and non-empty parameters 
            if ($request->type == "login" && $request->name != "" && $request->password  != "") {
                // Verify if the password matches
                    // Set token
                    // Execute the SQL
                    // Return the token
            }
        echo "Missing parameters!";
        }
    }
?>
```

If you despite all, want to see what is returned.. I have an example here (different operation, this is a delete operation instead of login but still the same result)

[image]

Edit:
Just censored some links.. apparently someone from France tried to access a non-existing folder on my server -.-

Comment: Someone down-voted my question .. Did I do something wrong asking about this? Please let me know so I can correct it if that's the case.

Comment: DELETE is not in your allowed methods so it will give a CORS error (status 0 in Angular)

Comment: "delete" is just a parameter I'm sending as a variable along with my data, it got nothing to do with the method I'm sending with or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using a self-signed cert:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ekstroms.xyz&latest

I presume you accepted this in Firefox and/or imported it into the Firefox trust store but you have not done this on your phone.

Comment: That may so be the issue!
Is there a "simple" way to "officially" sign it for free that you are aware of? - I've started googling already in hope to find something.

Comment: LetsEncrypt will provide you a free official cert. Check that out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your server to send the intermediate certificate.

Most probably you haven't specified 'SSLCertificateChainFile` and your phone can not recognize/validate your certificate.

**Note:** If You use self signed certificate then it will not be accepted automatically, You have to install it manually if possible!

If You need SSL certificate for private/non-commercial use, then You can get it from [here](https://www.startssl.com/)

Comment: I've used the "makecert" command through my CMD window as directed in this guide: http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords
SSL works on Firefox as mentioned in my post, that's what makes it extra odd.

Comment: If it is self signed certificate it will not be accepted by your phone!